# Rewrite directory to Query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory that list all residencies we have `http://example.com/residencies/` when you click on a residence it links to `http://example.com/residencies/myhouse` now I need .htaccess to rewrite the address to `http://example.com/residencies/details.php?id=myhouse`

I have

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)id= [NC]
  RewriteRule ^residencies/(.+)$ /residencies/details.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

This will make the redirect but is also try’s to redirect `http://example.com/residencies/`  to `http://example.com/residencies/details.php?id=`  what gives a error
How do I make it so it ignores the rewrite rule is there is no id?

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer to my own question for somebody who has the same question here is how i solved it

```
# residencies rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/residencies/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /residencies/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/residencies/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index.php|details.php) [NC]
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !id= [NC]
RewriteRule ^residencies/([^/]+)/?$ /residencies/details.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```